# I want to open file in asp.net and save it back after editing

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I open up an excel file in browser or simply open it make some changes and save it back again.? I have a file stored in my file system(drive) from where I need to read that file and open it make some changes and save it back again. My application is web based, I don't want it to ask me to open it or save it(like it gives for normal download), I just want to open like it opens in word or excel. Sole purpose of doing this is that I have that files stored centrally in my server which is accessible to user's. I just don't want versions of the file to be created. I want to have control on my editing.
           I know this cannot be done as per my knowledge, but again some % of facts are there that you don't know that you don't know ;-)

Please help with the same.

Comment: Definitely you are looking for a framework, perhaps Google-docs will fulfill your needs.

Comment: @celerno : any link as to how to use it in asp.net C# and I guess it will be paid.

Comment: Sounds like you should be looking into SharePoint integration

Comment: @Ankur Please answer this question: Do you need control over the edit process for a document? If yes, detail it at the main question. If don't, then you need a document management framework.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a text file, you could read it into a textbox, make your edits, and then just overwrite the old file.

Assuming you're working with a CSV file named "hello.csv", you can do something like this:

ASPX code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnRead" runat="server" Text="Read text file" 
            onclick="btnRead_Click" />

        <p><asp:TextBox ID="tb1" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Height="168px" Width="624px"></asp:TextBox></p>

        <p><asp:Button ID="btnWrite" runat="server" Text="Write text file" 
                onclick="btnWrite_Click" /></p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind:

Import the System.IO namespace.

```
protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileText;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("hello.csv")))
    {
        fileText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        tb1.Text = fileText;
        sr.Dispose();
    }
}

protected void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("hello.csv"));
    sw.Write(tb1.Text);
    sw.Dispose();
}
```

Depending on what you need to do you're probably going to have to tweak the approach, but this should get you started.

Comment: but what if the file is excel and in my case 95% it will be an excel file.

Comment: The op said "Can I open up an excel file in browser". So this is not a text file!

Comment: I've seen a lot of CSV files in web sites, which while they open in Excel they are, in fact, text files.